# App Service on Linux WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE actually read only volume?

Tags: caching, next.js, azure-web-app-service, cold-start

When using `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE` is it actually a read only volume that is mounted to `/home/site/wwwroot`?

I'm testing out the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE` app setting on a App service hosting a NextJS application on App service on linux. Because we are experiencing some serious latency on cold start, which we suspect is latency related to fetching module files from Azure Storage. The NextJS cache folder is deleted on publish or restart of site, but the site recreates the folder and add files (images) to the folder.
If the volume was read only this should not be possible, but maybe for some reason the setting is not activating the cache in my App service? How can I tell that the cache is active? Other than the environment setting.

The cache folder is located at `/home/site/wwwroot/.next/cache`.

I'm also facing av problem with disable the feature. After removing the setting, it is not possible to deploy new versions of the app. The deployment looks successfully i Azure DevOps release pipeline, but the web application still serves the old version. I had to re enable the cache by adding the app setting `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE` back, then do a new deploy, an finally the new version was served by the app service. Anyone experience the same?

Answer (score 0):

The `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE` setting in Azure App Service on Linux is used to enable or disable caching of files in the `/home/site/wwwroot` directory, where your application code resides.

**Read-Only Volume:**

- The `/home/site/wwwroot` directory itself is not a read-only volume, but the cache mechanism operates with a read-only copy of your application content during cold starts.
- During a cold start, Azure uses the cached version of your application to quickly spin up new instances. This cached directory is located at `/home/site/wwwroot/.appservice`.

**Verifying Cache Activation:**

- To confirm that the cache is active, you can access the "Advanced Tools" or "Kudu" interface for your App Service instance.

[image]

- In Kudu, navigate to the file system and check if the `.appservice` cache folder exists and contains files. If it's empty or missing, the cache might not be functioning correctly.

Comment: Cannot find the folder `.appservice`. 

But is the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/KuduLite/wiki/App-Cache) wrong?  

> The docker volume is then mounted onto the /home/site/wwwroot of the app and the app content is served from there

and also

> Currently the docker volume created is read only. So the app cannot write any file etc. onto the volume.

Comment: if you're not finding a .appservice directory in /home/site/wwwroot, it could be due to a few reasons. 1)The cache may not be enabled or active for your specific environment or app service plan. 2)The cache may not have been populated yet, as it typically happens during the initial cold start or when Azure deems it necessary.

Comment: I can also see that you have the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_CACHE` set to `1`, but in the documentation it is set to `true`. I use `true` Can that be the reason why the folder is not there?

Comment: Have you tried in your environment? After making this change, monitor your app to ensure that the cache is functioning as expected.

Comment: No I have not tried it, and it looks like it's working as expected to reduce the cold starts from 10 to 40 seconds down to almost 0. Only thing that is "off" is that the folder `.appservice` is missing. Do you have the information you provide me from inside the App Service Linux team?

Comment: I'm gratefull for you answer, but it still does not making me verify the activation of the cache. As it looks like it working, but no folder as you describe. I really hope the cache work the way you describe, that it uses a read-only cache, and that the wwwroot folder is not read-only. There is a lack of documentation on this topic and the documentation looks to me some how out dated. Maybe you have activated this feature for a long time ago, and thay have done som changes to how this works to day on new App services?